# what does "heuristically" means?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What does it mean when an author illustrates a result or proof of some result "heuristically" ? And why is that useful ?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic : In mathematics, some common heuristics involve the use of visual representations, additional assumptions, forward/backward reasoning and simplification.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of this being used that you would like explained? In general I would think it means that they're showing an argument which has merit but doesn't go through rigorously, in order to establish why a result makes sense intuitively

Comment: It's an unproven, not-quite-universal algorithm that is still nonetheless effective.

Comment: I agree with Stephen. I have nothing to add to SomeCallMeTim's excellent answer except to note another place where it is very common to do this. In analytic number theory, a common heuristic is that large primes are distributed randomly. Of course this is completely false: whether a number is prime or not is deterministic. But proceeding with this assumption has had a long history of leading to "the right answers", and so people will often justify their conjectures *heuristically* in this sense.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan: *Can you give a specific example* --- See [Most harmful heuristic?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2358/15780) *AND* [Most useful heuristic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1977134/13130) *AND* [Examples in number theory where a heuristic argument fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695405/13130) *AND* [What are some historical examples in physics of heuristic proofs of mathematical results?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12307/264) *AND* [What does one mean by heuristic statistical physics arguments?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1130) FYI, I was at NCSU 89-93.

Comment: I associate heuristical reasoning with sensible informal shortcuts via which results or correctness isn't *guaranteed*. @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the links; a 'automathography'? Who knew!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very common example: We define the Riemann integral as sums of rectangles approximating the area under the curve, and then take the limit as the "width" of the rectangles go towards zero. This, along with the picture, is a more or less *heuristic* definition of the Riemann integral, in that the formalism is not in focus, but we concentrate on visualization and understanding.

[image: Rieman integral]

Picture is from https://isquared.digital/blog/2020-05-27-riemann-integration/